# How to write HTML line using Razor?

Tags: html, razor, html-table, datatable, datatables

I am working on a table according to the molds of the image below

[image]

However, to adapt the different amounts of lines in line 3 I made this code

```
<tbody>
        @{var foco = 3;}


        @for (int x = 0; x < foco; x++)
        {
            <tr>
                @{if (x == 0) {"<td rowspan='" + foco + "' class='col-md-3'>1</td>";}}
                <td class="col-md-2">2</td>
                <td class="col-md-5">3</td>
                <td class="col-md-2">4</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

How can I make the if text to be displayed on the screen?

edit:
In short, my goal is that I can make a table in which one of the fields has 3 other equivalent fields (can have more or less depending on the need), and for this I need the code above to create these fields unified for me, but I can not perform this 3td process are aligned with 1td higher

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want the HTML to be a literal string in the server-side code.  Instead, you want your server-side code to simply wrap your normal HTML markup.  Pretty much identical to the syntax you already use in your `for` structure, the only difference being that you also appear to want to output a value within the HTML.  The same `@`-notation is used for that as well.

Something like this:

```
@for (int x = 0; x < foco; x++)
{
    <tr>
        @if (x == 0)
        {
            <td rowspan="@foco" class="col-md-3">1</td>
        }
        <td class="col-md-2">2</td>
        <td class="col-md-5">3</td>
        <td class="col-md-2">4</td>
    </tr>
}
```

(Note that this isn't really a C# thing, this is specific to Razor view engine syntax.)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the easiest way to fulfill your goal is using JS DOM mechanism (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). It allows you to manipulate HTML elements dynamically.

You don't need to worry about razor specific syntax etc.

In your case:

1) Create empty placeholder for the table, just specify some Id:

```
<tbody id="my-table-body">
</tbody>
```

2) In the script section invoke your logic:

```
@section Scripts{

    var foco = 3;

    //get table body reference
    var myTableBody = document.getElementById("my-table-body");

    for (int x = 0; x < foco; x++) {
        if(x == 0) {

            //create td element and fill its properites
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            td.rowSpan = foco.toString();
            td.className = "col-md-3";
            td.value = 1

            //add the td element to table body
            myTableBody.appendChild(td);
        }
    }
}
```